# Populating DataGridComboBox in Grid with SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to get a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` (Or `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ComboBox`) to populate a list of ports and default each row to the port that is already stored in the database. I have got a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ComboBox` populating the Ports, but I cannot seem to get it to select what is already stored in the database.

I'm using Entity Framework and I have 2 tables, 'Route' and 'Port'. 'Route' has 2 foreign keys for a 'Destination Port' and a 'Arrival Port'.

I have 2 ObervableCollections, one for the list of ports, and another for the list of routes. In the routes collection there is a 'Port1' and 'Port2' for Destination/Arrival respectively.

This is what I currently have:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.PortCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                          DisplayMemberPath="PortName"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.RouteCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.Port1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                                          SelectedValuePath="PortId">
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

But as I said it is only listing the available ports, and is otherwise blank. Sorry if I haven't made myself too clear, I'm not very good at articulating, generally.

Here are my collections:

```
public ObservableCollection<Port> PortCollection { get; set; }

//List of Routes
private ObservableCollection<Route> _RouteCollection;

public ObservableCollection<Route> RouteCollection
{
    get { return _RouteCollection; }
    set
    {
        _RouteCollection = value;
        Set(() => RouteCollection, ref _RouteCollection, value);
    }
}
```

There's clearly something obvious wrong as this must be quite a common thing to do, but I've been going mad for 4 hours on this just getting this far! :(

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Port1" is supposed to be a property of the item in the `DataGrid`'s `Items` collection. It should have the same type as the `PortId` property of the `Port` class.

You can then bind the `SelectedValue` property directly to it like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.PortCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="PortName"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding Port1}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="PortId">
```

The default `DataContext` of an element in the `CellTemplate` of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` is the corresponding item in the `Items`/`ItemsSource` collection of the parent `DataGrid`.

Note that if the type of the `Port1` property is `Port` you should use the `SelectedItem` property instead of `SelectedValue`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.PortCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="PortName"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Port1}">
```